# Rudin's RCA, Chapter 2 Definitions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am currently reading Rudin's RCA, and I have some questions about a particular definition he uses in chapter 2:

The following passage is taken from Rudin's RCA, page 47, section 2.15:

"A measure $\mu$ defined on the $\sigma$-algebra of all Borel sets in a locally compact Hausdorff space $X$ is called a $\textit{Borel measure}$ on $X$. If $\mu$ is positive, a Borel set $E \subset X$ is outer regular, or inner regular, respectively, if $E$ has property (x) or (d) of Theorem 2.14. If every Borel set in $X$ is both outer and inner regular, then $\mu$ is called regular."

1.) I find that in certain theorems of this text (in particular, Theorem 2.17), he talks about a measure defined on a $\sigma$-algebra that can properly contain the set of Borel sets of a locally compact Hausdorff space, yet he still refers to the measure as Borel, not abiding to his definition (his definition states that Borel measures must on the $\sigma$-algebra of Borel sets). He also calls such measures regular.

Does he mean that the measure, when restricted down to the $\sigma$-algebra of Borel sets of the space, is a Borel measure? And when he says that the measure is regular (as in Theorem 2.17), does he mean that the measure is regular in the more general sense, or only in the sense where it's regular if the $\sigma$-algebra is restricted down the sigma algebra of borel sets?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when Rudin says "Borel measure" he means some measure defined on but not necessarily only on every Borel set. You may restrict this measure to one defined on the $\sigma$-algebra containing only Borel sets, and the regularity will hold, because open sets and compact sets are all Borel sets.

In general, our purpose is to work on complete measures, like the ones given by the Riesz representation theorem.